# MAUI: Download and store images

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I have a project for a mobile app that will show a catalog of products from a JSON url, I want to store all those products in cache so that if the user has no internet, he can still see the products (assuming first load)

What would be the correct approach for this in terms of images? If I start download all the images it would take too much time for the first render, and since the image has to be downloaded to show in an Imag tag, is there a way to combine it? Meaning the first time a image is loaded into the Image it will also be stored internally, so I can later use it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image?view=net-maui-7.0#image-caching

Comment: should I just put like a month cache or something like that?

Comment: I don't know.  Will that satisfy your requirements?  If you truly need the images offline, then downloading them in the background is probably best.  Or you could write you own ImageSource that handles downloading and caching to meet your needs.

Comment: @SafinAhmed I also recommend what Jason said. I am using this (for shortening, not prolonging).

Answer (score 3):

You can set the image cache in image, the image cache is enabled by default, but the cached image is only saved for 1 day. The property CacheValidity in UriImageSource can specify how long the image will be stored locally. You can set it to the time you need, like this:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <UriImageSource Uri="https://aka.ms/campus.jpg"
                        CacheValidity="10:00:00:00" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

You can refer to the documentation for more:[Image caching | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image?view=net-maui-7.0#image-caching)